# Data collator not set in trainer class?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am training a language model using a Hugging face model. I am using a RoBERTa model and I am getting a problem when training. This is how I create the Trainer class using a DataCollatorForLanguageModeling as data_collator.

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=collator,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    tokenizer=tokenizer
    #prediction_loss_only=True,
)
```

However, when I call `trainer.get_train_dataloader().collate_fn` it is using a RemoveColumnsCollator. I think this is the reason why the training is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found out this is a wrapper class for the data collator passed as an argument. It is possible to find it by doing

```
trainer.get_train_dataloader().collate_fn.data_collator
```